# LINQ: Why can't I declare new objects in returned object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, properties

First of all, I did some searching for an answer to this question...but I couldn't find anything cause I don't know what the functionality I'm using is called.

The DBEntities in the below code was generated by devart for an Oracle DB connection.

**Why does the first example work and the second one only gives me a System.NullReferenceException?**

Valid code:

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
{
    var infos = (from info in context.Infos
                 where info.Index == index
                 orderby info.Name
                 select new
                 {
                     Name = info.Name,
                     MRN = info.MRN,
                     UnitNumber = (info.UnitNum == null) ? -1 : (decimal)info.UnitNum,
                     UnitName = (info.UnitName == null) ? String.Empty : info.UnitName
                 }).Distinct();

    foreach (var info in infos)
    {
        // *do stuff*
    }
}
```

Code that gives exception (Exception is only seen once the foreach is reached):

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
{
    var infos = (from info in context.Infos
                 where info.Index == index
                 orderby info.Name
                 select new Member()
                 {
                     Name = info.Name,
                     MRN = info.MRN,
                     CurrentUnit = new Unit()
                     {
                         UnitNumber = (info.UnitNum == null) ? -1 : (decimal)info.UnitNum,
                         UnitName = (info.UnitName == null) ? String.Empty : info.UnitName
                     }
                 }).Distinct();

    foreach (Member info in infos)
    {
        // *do stuff*
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I would like to add that this works as well:

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
{
    var infos = (from info in context.Infos
                 where info.Index == index
                 orderby info.Name
                 select new Member()
                 {
                     Name = info.Name,
                     MRN = info.MRN
                 }).Distinct();

    foreach (Member info in infos) //Exception is thrown here.
    {
        // *do stuff*
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @Thebigcheeze System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Are yuo sure your collection contains a data?

Comment: @Tigran Yes, I've tested with a direct connection to the DB and the top code runs, returning what I'm expecting when index is the same value for both sets of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one works because you can return those anonymous types from SQL and EF can generate a SQL statement for the whole expression.  The second one doesn't because you can't create an instance of the Member class in SQL.  If you forced the enumeration to happen (using AsEnumerable()) you could create the Member value client side.

The exception will always be thrown at the point of enumeration because LINQ is, by design, entirely 'lazy'.  If you want to force it to happen at the point you create the expression (for testing purposes, say), then add `.ToList()` to the end of it.

Comment: So you're saying that I just can't create a new instance of an object as I do with CurrentUnit when using LINQ with entity but I can if I were doing it on an Enumerable object? Just clarifying.

Comment: No, he's saying that, in your particular situation, you have to force Linq to execute, by telling it you need the value(s) now.

Comment: Always think about which parts of your query expression will evaluate on the database and which will evaluate on the client.  Anything before a .ToList(), .ToArray(), .AsEnumerable() will happen on the SQL Server so if your expression cannot be evaluated there it will fail.  EF makes no attempt to figure out where to put the boundary and just blindly assumes it can do as much as possible in SQL.

Comment: I tried adding .ToList()...and now I just get the exeption earlier.

Comment: Yeah, if you add it to the END of the expression it will just move the exception back to that line.  If you insert it between the where and the select `context.infos.Where(...).ToList().Select(...).Distinct(...)` you'll get different results.

Comment: @Brandon where did you put the ToList?  You need to put it before the `select new Member()` bit, because that's the bit that can't execute on the server.

Comment: I'd suggesting using `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()`. It functions just as well as a boundary between server and client side processing, but has the added benefit of not eager loading data. E.g. some code path may decide never to actually enumerate the data in which case you save yourself a database hit. Plus I believe it more explicitly documents the location and the intent of client side processing, since it stands out as saying "stop trying to SQL-ify anything beyond this point".

Comment: @Hightechrider doing the .Where(...).ToList().Select(...) worked! Though I don't like it much...at least I know why it's not working now. I mean, what's the difference between that and just doing the first code I posted and then while iterating over the elements, creating new objects that will be used later? It seems to take a bit of a performance hit too...though, it's not huge.

Comment: @Hightechrider Another thing I'm wondering now: Why can I create the new Member but not something within the new Member? This still doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
foreach (Member info in infos) //Exception is thrown here.
{
    // *do stuff*
}
```

use

```
foreach (var info in infos) //Valid.
{
    // *do stuff*
}
```

This is because `infos` return anonymus result. which is not fully `Member` collection class.

Comment: But in the example with `foreach (Member ...`, the query instantiates `Member` instances, not anonymous instances.

Comment: @phoog. You're not iterating fully qualified Member collection class. Like List<Member> collection class. That is why you have to use var instead of Member class.

Comment: That's just not true.  If you have a query with `select new Member()` as its select clause, it will return an `IEnumerable<Member>`, and `foreach (Member...` will work just fine.  The exception is happening for another reason (see Hightechrider's answer).

Comment: @phoog. Well it's not know what are the properties of Member class. That's what I answered this way. If you're not assigning all properties of the Member class, this is the perfect answer for you qn.

Comment: @Wonde phoog is correct, I've tested this and have added an edit to my question to show such.